# Orientação de página no xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Estou começando a programar usando o xamarin forms, criei uma tela de cadastro, porém quando mudo a orientação da tela para horizontal ela não ativa o scroll e os botões ficam ocultos. 
Segue o código da tela:

```
<StackLayout>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label FontSize="Medium">Nome Fornecedor:</Label>
        <Entry x:Name="NomeForecedor"></Entry>
        <Label FontSize="Medium">Cidade Fornecedor:</Label>
        <Entry x:Name="CidadeForecedor"></Entry>
        <Label FontSize="Medium">CNPJ:</Label>
        <Entry x:Name="Cnpj"></Entry>
        <Label FontSize="Medium">Estado:</Label>
        <Entry x:Name="EstadoForecedor"></Entry>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="btnSalvar"   
                BackgroundColor="Azure" 
                Text="Salvar" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnCancelar" 
                BackgroundColor="Azure"
                Text="Cancelar" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
    </StackLayout>


</StackLayout>
```

**Obs:** Estou usando um [ContentPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage/).

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que adicionar um *ScrollView* na sua Page.

Coloque o código que deseja 'scrollar' dentro da tag *ScrollView*.

Abaixo segue um exemplo com seu código:

```
<StackLayout>

 <ScrollView>
   <StackLayout>
       <Label FontSize="Medium">Nome Fornecedor:</Label>
       <Entry x:Name="NomeForecedor"></Entry>
       <Label FontSize="Medium">Cidade Fornecedor:</Label>
       <Entry x:Name="CidadeForecedor"></Entry>
       <Label FontSize="Medium">CNPJ:</Label>
       <Entry x:Name="Cnpj"></Entry>
       <Label FontSize="Medium">Estado:</Label>
       <Entry x:Name="EstadoForecedor"></Entry>
   </StackLayout>

   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="btnSalvar"   
            BackgroundColor="Azure" 
            Text="Salvar" 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnCancelar" 
            BackgroundColor="Azure"
            Text="Cancelar" 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
      </StackLayout>
 </ScrollView>

</StackLayout>
```

Caso queira mostrar o ScrollView apenas quando a tela mudar de orientação, você pode usar o exemplo do artigo abaixo:

- [Xamarin Forms Orientation](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/screen-orientation/)

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seja melhor você utilizar um Relative Layout pois dependendo pode não ser legal para o usuário um scroll em uma tela de cadastro.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/